# VBA code to not insert if data already in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro which is so close to what I need. The issue I have is if the data is already in sheet2 it inserts a new line and the same data where as I don't want it duplicated. I have tried a few things but I cant quite get there

```
'start with sheet 1
 Sheets(1).Activate
 Dim rowStartSheet1, rowStartSheet2, lastRowSheet1, lastRowSheet2 As Integer

'change this variable if your row doesn't start on 2 as in this example for sheet1 and sheet2
rowStartSheet1 = 2
rowStartSheet2 = 2

'gets you the last row in sheet 1
 lastRowSheet1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 'this entire for block is to check if a data row in sheet 1 is in sheet 2 and if so, copy and paste the rest of the data points
For i = rowStartSheet1 To lastRowSheet1

'case 1 where column C matches column A first time around (no duplicates)
'change this variable if sheet 2 starts on a different row
Sheets(2).Activate

lastRowSheet2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'loops through sheet 2 column A to check if it matches what we want in sheet1 Column C
For ii = rowStartSheet2 To lastRowSheet2

    'inputs if found first time around
    If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3) = Cells(ii, 1) And Cells(ii, 7) = "" Then
        Cells(ii, 7) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(ii, 8) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        Exit For

    'if sheet2 column G already has info in it, create a new row
    ElseIf Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3) = Cells(ii, 1) And Cells(ii, 7) <> "" Then
        Rows(ii).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        Cells(ii, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Cells(ii, 7) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(ii, 8) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        Exit For
    End If

 Next ii
 Next i
 End Sub
```

All help appreciated
[SHEET1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI9Ao.png)
[SHEET2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fXeL.png)

Comment: What is the "same data" in this case?  What are you matching on?

Answer (score 0):

In my code below I refer to columns by their name (like "A", "B") instead of their number as you have done. This isn't intended as criticism. On the contrary, I much prefer to use numbers and usually declare them in enumerations. However, I felt that you might find my code more readable with the syntax I chose.

```
Sub CopyUniqueItems()
    ' 09 Aug 2017

    Const RsFirst As Long = 2
    Const RtFirst As Long = 2
    Const Lot As Long = 1
    Const Part As Long = 2
    Const Col As Long = 3

    Dim WsS As Worksheet                    ' S = Source
    Dim WsT As Worksheet                    ' T = Target
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Itm As Variant
    Dim Rs As Long, RsLast As Long          ' Row / last row in WsS
    Dim Rt As Variant, RtLast As Long       ' Row / last row in WsT

    Set WsS = Worksheets(1)                 ' { better to call by name
    Set WsT = Worksheets(2)                 ' { like Worksheets("Sheet2")
    RsLast = WsS.Cells(WsS.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Rs = RsFirst To RsLast
        With WsS
            Itm = .Range(.Cells(Rs, "A"), .Cells(Rs, "C")).Value
        End With
        With WsT
            RtLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            With .Columns("A")
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(RtFirst), .Cells(RtLast))
            End With
            On Error Resume Next
            Rt = Application.Match(Itm(1, Lot), Rng, 0)
            If IsError(Rt) Then
                ' not found
                Rt = Application.Max(RtLast + 1, RtFirst)
            Else
                ' exists already
                Rt = Rt + RtFirst - 1
                Do
                    If (.Cells(Rt, "G").Value = Itm(1, Part)) And _
                       (.Cells(Rt, "H").Value = Itm(1, Col)) Then
                       Rt = 0
                       Exit Do
                    Else
                        Rt = Rt + 1
                    End If
                Loop While .Cells(Rt, "A").Value = Itm(1, Lot)
                .Rows(Rt).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            End If

            If Rt Then
                .Cells(Rt, "A").Value = Itm(1, Lot)
                .Cells(Rt, "G").Value = Itm(1, Part)
                .Cells(Rt, "H").Value = Itm(1, Col)
            End If
        End With
    Next Rs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

BTW, `Dim rowStartSheet1, rowStartSheet2, lastRowSheet1, lastRowSheet2 As Integer` declares only `lastRowSheet2` as integer. All the others are undefined and therefore variants.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. I can't see where you are dealing with the following part of my macro                                                                                                              `'if sheet2 column G already has info in it, create a new row
    ElseIf Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3) = Cells(ii, 1) And Cells(ii, 7) <> "" Then
        Rows(ii).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        Cells(ii, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Cells(ii, 7) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(ii, 8) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)`

Comment: :-)  Trace the variable `CopyData`. If no match is found it will take the value `CopyAll`. Else it will take the value `CopySome` or `CopyNone` in this line, `CopyData = CInt(CBool(Len(WsT.Cells(Rt, "G").Value))) + 1`. Further down, action is taken according to the value of `CopyData`.

Comment: Hi @Variatus. I thought that was the part dealing with it, It's not inserting any rows though and as I don't really understand it I cant really see why, sorry. would it help if I uploaded an example of the workbook?

Comment: Yes. I suggest we try that.

Comment: Hi @Variatus...sheet1 and sheet2 links edited into original post. Hope it makes sense

Comment: The pictures of your sheets aren't useful because I can't copy them. Reading your post again it seems that you want an extra row added for the same item if column G already has information. My code doesn't do that. Is that what you want? Where should the duplicate row go? At the end? Or below the existing?

Comment: Hi @Variatus. Sorry couldn't see how to upload a workbook. Maybe this will help a bit sheet1 column A are part numbers, B are colours and C are prod lots.This sheet is used as a set up sheet to add information to sheet2 and will be constantly updated.    In Sheet2 column A the prod lot(this is permanent), G is the part numbers and H are the colours(both added from sheet1).  Yes correct if sheet2 column G has data then insert an extra row below the existing...As sheet1 is constantly updated if the data has already been inserted in sheet2 I don't want it inserted again (as per your code already)

Comment: I have re-done the code and tested it. It should be fine now.

Comment: Hi  @Variatus. Thanks again for your help .. I have tested the new code and if I run the macro over and over it is inserting the data into sheet2 over and over

Comment: Yes. You did say that. Sorry. I have amended the code above.